# Is there a way to make custom posts type pagination work on a page with a slug similar to their rewrite slug?

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

That sort of problem seems to be very 'popular' and I tried a couple of possible solutions already. None of them helped me, either I have disabled pagination either I get disabled permalinks. I hope some of you figured out how to make it work.

Problem: I want to make my custom post type 'pt_news' work on a page with a slug 'news', so it could be beautiful urls such as `/news/news-about-something/`.

I use a plugin 'Posts in Pages' to perform an output, but I also tried manual output via wp-query which is often recommended to solve pagination problem. None of that methods worked.

If I use `PiP type of pagination` it gives me urls `/news/?page=2` then Wordpress makes it to `/news/2/` and tells me there is not such page, if I use `wp-query` it generates `/news/pages/2/` when I try to enter that it says sorry there is nothing to display and sends me to some sort of 'Latest Posts'. Permalinks are set to `/%postname%/`. I tried `/%category%/%postname%/` as well, although it should be useless here.

The only way which made pagination to work correctly and custom posts type objects to open was to disable permalinks. I don't like that idea but having a fight with wordpress for 1.5 days I was not able to find a solution. Could you suggest something for that case?

P.S. I have that pagination fixes:

```
function advanced_wp_pagination(){
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999;
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ));
}

function remove_page_from_query_string($query_string){

    if ($query_string['name'] == 'page' && isset($query_string['page'])) {
        unset($query_string['name']);
        // 'page' in the query_string looks like '/2', so i'm spliting it out
        list($delim, $page_index) = split('/', $query_string['page']);
        $query_string['paged'] = $page_index;
    }      
    return $query_string;
}

add_filter('request', 'remove_page_from_query_string');

function fix_category_pagination($qs){
    if(isset($qs['category_name']) && isset($qs['paged'])){
        $qs['post_type'] = get_post_types($args = array(
            'public'   => true,
            '_builtin' => false
        ));
        array_push($qs['post_type'],'pt-news');
    }
    return $qs;
}
add_filter('request', 'fix_category_pagination');
```

Comment: This might just solve your issue: https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/tw-pagination/

Comment: No that plugin has nothing to do with an issue. It simply generates more advanced pagination links, I do it without it. It does not work. I have link /news/page/2/ for example, but it sends me to 'latest posts' with a record 'sorry nothing to display'

Comment: I need only to make pagination work, I have discovered it does not work at all, even if I disable permalinks generation.